# How change the order of 'this' when passing it through bind in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following code do illustrate my problem.

```
var p = Promise.resolve('this-is-the-title');
createFilePath=(title, ex)=>{
  let ready = `${title.split(' ').join('-')}.${ex}`
  console.log(ready)
  return Promise.resolve(ready)
}
makeFile=(path,content)=>{
  return{
    file: path,
    content
  }
}
p
  .then(createFilePath.bind(this,'md'))
```

What will be logged is `md.this-is-the-title`. Is there a way to change the order of `this` (something like `.then(createFilePath.bind('md', this))`)

`createFilePath` is used by other functions so I would not like to go through the code and change `createFilePath(ex,title)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently your use of `bind` is equivalent to this:

```
p.then(function(promiseValue) {
    return createFilePath.call(this, 'md', promiseValue)
})
```

Here the `promiseValue` is the value of the promise `p`, which is `'this-is-the-title'` in your example. `bind` is being used to 'partially apply' the arguments of the function `createFilePath` but you can only do that from left-to-right, you can't skip over the first argument and just specify the second argument. You can do it yourself using a wrapper function:

```
p.then(function(promiseValue) {
    return createFilePath.call(this, promiseValue, 'md')
})
```

If you don't need the `this` value inside `createFilePath` (which you don't in your example but you might in your real code) then you can simplify this further:

```
p.then(function(promiseValue) {
    return createFilePath(promiseValue, 'md')
})
```

Comment: I thought there was a way to do that without the extra anonymous function